# Designing an air transformer based rotary encoder

Tags: coil, induction

I want to make a rotary encoder with air coils. Before I make it I want to check with the pros so I don't waste time ordering 3D-printed parts that will never work. I am aware that the output coils sense two rotations per actual rotation, but I'll always put the rotor at a known angle at startup so it's not a problem for me. I know I can do the same thing with a permanent magnet and two hall effect sensors but I don't want that solution. Wire is cheaper than a magnet and hall effect sensors. I can always add more turns on the sensors to increase their sensitivity.

The rotor size will have a diameter of 1 cm (~half inch) and be made of plastic. I will submerge one shorted air coil into the plastic rotor and place three similar coils that are not shorted around the rotor. See figure 1 that I made below. The three outer coils are all connected to ground on one end, they are also fixed in place, rolled around some plastic, they are stationary.

[image]
Figure 1: GIF animation showing the amplitude and phase of the two sensor coils.

The coil to the left is connected to a sine wave generator, I can choose whatever frequency I want but I'll go with 10 kHz because it's annoying to listen to and if I hear a peep I know that something is loose.

The coil at the top is sensor A, the coil to the right is sensor B. I assume that their outputs will be very low given a 1:1 ratio, therefor they will go into individual amplification stages and then to a µC. Or I will just add more turns to the sensing coils and set the DC point with with a capacitor and resistors. At the µC the amplitude and phase will be measured compared to the sine wave generator.

The red arrows indicate the relative amplitude and phase measured at sensor A and sensor B compared to the sine wave generator. It is in the complex plane with only real numbers, so the phase is either 0 or 180.

The hexagon is supposed to indicate that the shorted coil is submerged inside of it. It is the plastic rotor.

The green arrow just indicate that rotation angle and the fact that one actual rotation should make the sensors indicate that two rotations has passed. So this is something I have to take into account.

---

Here is an overall schematic of the rotary encoder.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqGP2d.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

---

The voltage I hope to see at sensor A and sensor B are:

\$\text{sensor A} = \text{C}\sin(2\phi)\sin(10000t2\pi)\$ volt
\$\text{sensor B} = \text{K}\cos(2\phi)\sin(10000t2\pi)\$ volt

Where:

- \$\phi\$ is the rotor angle in radians
- \$C\$ is some constant that depends on the geometric shape and power and N turns
- \$K\$ is some constant that depends on the geometric shape and power and N turns

The phase is binary, either 0 or 180, as can be seen in the GIF above.

---

**Do you see any obvious problem with this idea, or some problem I might encounter?** 
Is my understanding of shorted and cascaded air transformers correct or super wrong?

Comment: Your rotary shorted coil will only be coupled to the "disturber" coil when it's in line with it.  When it's crossways (coupled to the top coil) it won't be coupled to the input.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to reinvent the synchro.  You may want to look into how those work.

Comment: At your first comment: I was imagining that the rotary shorted coil would be coupled to all three and then the "disturber" would be coupled to the sensors via the rotary shorted coil - I wanted to essentially just have my disturber inside the rotor, but doing so will require me to use a slip ring of some sort.

Comment: At your second comment: Oh woaw, yeah a [synchro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchro) is exactly what I was reinventing. Heh, it's hard to do research when you don't know what it's actually called.

Comment: The problem with the synchro though is that it requires a slip ring. Oh well, I can actually make a rotary transformer to solve that problem.

Comment: Diablo daisywheel printers used a magnetic encoder to sense the position of the printwheel and carriage, with disc-shaped "rotor" and "stator" pieces. It output a quadurature triangle waveform. It did not use slip rings. Have a look here: http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/diablo/printer/630/90443-02A_Diablo_630_630ECS_Maint_Mar83.pdf

Comment: Better link for Diablo: ftp://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/diablo/printer/1620/82333C_1610_1620_Mantenance_Manual_Dec78.pdf See page 2-22.

Comment: And a contemporary application of the same technique: https://www.celeramotion.com/zettlex/products/incoder-inductive-encoders/

Comment: @hacktastical I've looked a bit at your links and I can't say 100% that I understand how they work. I bet it's super simple, I just can't wrap my head around it. Visually it looks like your typical [rotary encoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotary_encoder#See_also) with two LED's and two sensors. Which I assume is why on page 2-22 and the "IncOder series" by Zettlex have so many loops around the edge. Either way, wiring that physically would be a real pain in the a**, I suppose I could make a PCB of it, but who knows what kind of patents I might be infringing on.

Comment: These examples are incremental encoders. What you would do is something more like a syncho, using a flat disk rotary transformer for the coupling to the drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better bet would be, with your B sensors on the X axis, and A on Z, put your excitation on the Y axis. It's now coupled to neither of the output axes. It can sit above or below, or go right round the outside, it doesn't matter.

Tilt your rotor coil by 45 degrees, so it's partially coupled to Y, and partially coupled to a direction in the XZ plane, which you sense by detecting the sine/cosine reception in the A and B coils as before.

Comment: To make sure I understand you crystal clear, I keep sensor A and sensor B in their orientations and make "disturber" go around the entire thing perpendicular to them both. And tilt the one in the rotor by 45 degrees.

Comment: @HarrySvensson That's all correct, the key thing being the disturber perpendicular to them both, so not coupling to either A or B if the rotor was absent. Note you could also use something like a piece of ferrite rod instead of the coil, also tilted at 45 degrees, in the rotor. What you'd have, noting one of your comments, is effectively a 2 phase synchro energised with a rotary transformer instead of sliprings. As such, you could also sine/cosine enrgise the A and B coils, and phase detect what's induced in the disturber, if that was easier to do.

Comment: I'll mark this one as correct, since you mentioned synchro and came up with a much better setup for my coils so I can get the angle of the rotor from the phase instead of amplitude which is much much better. And yeah, powering the sensors and measuring the disturber is most likely what I'm going to do, and then put a goertzel filter on it in software where I time the sampling frequency correctly so I just get 1, i, -1, -i as my coefficients. - This is great.